# How can I divide a vector in c++

Tags: c++11, vector, c++14, stdvector

Ive tried with assign fxn but it doesnt work

```
c.assign(v.begin(), v.begin() + (v.size() + 1) / 2)
d.assign(v.begin() + (v.size() + 1) / 2 + 1, v.end())
```

for eg vec = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
then it produces result
vec1 = 1,2,3,4
vec2 = 6,7,8

Comment: So there is an error in your calculations. To understand and correct it, answer these simple questions: how many elements are in `c.assign(v.begin(),v.begin()+3)`? Which elements are these? How do you get to the first element NOT assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the output is exactly as expected.  Remember, the pair of iterators that you present to `assign` is a half-open interval--i.e.:

```
c.assign(b,e);
```

assigns to `c` the values corresponding to `b` through `e-1`.  But you have added 1 to the iterator in the `d.assign` statement.

For your code to work how you intend, you'll want:

```
auto const b = v.cbegin();
auto const m = b+(v.size()+1)/2;
auto const e = v.cend();

c.assign(b,m);
d.assign(m,e);
```